# How do I default to international search in Google?

Tags: google-search, google-chrome

I have now reached the threshold for the amount of time I want to spend searching for how to disable a feature. I'm unsure if it's a Google feature or a Google Chrome feature. How do I search internationally by default, and not only in Norway (Norge) as illulstrated here?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried changing the language setting to English?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the bottom right of the Google home page, there is a link "Use Google.com". On clicking that, you subsequent searches will happen from Google.com.